# voltage level of mp3 mobile phones

Tags: amplifier

What are the voltage level (pk to pk, both average and the maximum voltage output) of a music player from Samsung mobile phones, Apple iPods, iPhones etc. I dont have a multimeter here and those devices above. I cannot find on the internet the device specifications that list those voltage levels. Ill be designing an audio preamplifier and so we need these data to aid in dc biasing calculations.

If have oscilloscope, that would be better and a graph for it

Comment: Across what headphone impedance?

Comment: I'm plugging the mobile phone to a pre amplifier.

Comment: I guess I need to know the voltage levels of a mobile phone before designing a prwamplifier right???

Comment: If you're plugging in a signal that is capable of driving headphones, why do you need a preamplifier? What, by your understanding, is a preamplifier?

Comment: A preamplfier is a device that amplifies the small signal from mobile phones typically around 300 mv to around 5 or more volts and it passes the amplified signal to power amplifier for driving large speakers

Comment: Well I will not drive a headphone( I'll be driving an amplifier delivering 30 watts of power

Comment: Sorry, I think there is some additional research needed here. Voting to close.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6504/discussion-between-vvavepacket-and-anindo-ghosh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog post](http://blog.reinforce-lab.com/2010/10/iphonegettingpowerfromaudioplug.html) may help you out some. It states that the output voltage from an iPhone is about 0.95 Vrms.